Lpr does not work
This is a thunar custom action. It should let me print whatever file is highlighted in my file manager. It no longer works.
lpr %f

My printer environmental variable is set, so it should work. ??

~$ printenv
SHELL=/bin/bash

LPDEST=HL-2240


I can print just fine when I open an editor and print from there.
Re-installing the drivers did not help.

lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: HL-2240-series
device for HL-2240-series: usb://Brother/HL-2240%20series?serial=B4N935575
device for HL2240: usb://Brother/HL-2240%20series?serial=B4N935575
HL-2240-series accepting requests since Fri 20 Sep 2024 07:38:31 AM CDT
HL2240 accepting requests since Fri 20 Sep 2024 07:26:55 AM CDT
printer HL-2240-series is idle. enabled since Fri 20 Sep 2024 07:38:31 AM CDT
printer HL2240 is idle. enabled since Fri 20 Sep 2024 07:26:55 AM CDT

Does this mean that my default printer is working and that lpr just does not work?

lpstat -t

scheduler is running
system default destination: HL-2240-series
device for HL-2240-series: usb://Brother/HL-2240%20series?




thunar is an Xfce program, yet you mention Ubuntu-MATE in tags???  The equivalent MATE application is caja which uses/shares the resources used by the MATE desktop rather than uses Xfce resources.

@guiverc Thunar works fine with Ubuntu Mate. And it has more features than Caja.

All file-managers will work; and if your machine has the resources to spare & you can ignore what will be most efficient and use whatever you like.

@guiverc I have 8 Gb of memory. I use less than 2 Gb in heavy use.

I don't have the reputations to put this in as a comment -
This looks a lot like Unable to print with lpr command
I use lpr a lot.  I always specify a printer (lpr -P xxxx)
To address the comment on this answer that it did not work, I created a launcher then dropped a file on the launcher - it printed.  My printer has the name BS3.  The system is XUbuntu 24
----------------------
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=lprTEST
Comment=
Exec=lpr -P BS3 %f
Icon=
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false



It did not work.

@fixit7 You have accepted this answer as well as leaving the comment: 'It does not work'. Could you clarify please...

@andrew46 I unchecked the acceptance button.

@Zeye I have only seen the %f in a Thunar custom action. Is it a replaceable parameter?

At first %f was a guess but then, I made the above icon for XFCE and dropped a file on the icon to be sure.  It worked

libreoffice -p %f

Many programs have options to print. ;-)
